# Since installing 10.15.7 Catalina terminal is now using zsh

Tags: node.js

The NODE.js installation summary requested that I "Make sure that usr/local/bin is in your $PATH"

When I run npm install I get this:
saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/iancraig/package.json'

When I run echo $PATH I get this: /Users/iancraig/.nvm/versions/node/v10.17.0/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

Why is the existing path so long? How can I repair this situation and run npm successfully? I'm running OS 10.15.7 Catalina.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be an issue with your node installation rather the directory in which you're running npm install. You might be running it in your pc home directory instead of in your project directory. Give that a try and if you get that error again, run `npm init` and go through the steps before installing any dependencies

Answer (score 0):

## why is my path so long?

Your path is the normal length. It is a modest list of paths your system searces when looking for executables. The colons are seperators, so your $PATH is composed of these directories:

1. /Users/iancraig/.nvm/versions/node/v10.17.0/bin
2. /usr/local/bin
3. /usr/bin
4. /bin
5. /usr/sbin
6. /sbin

## npm install

`npm install` is a command that expects a `package.json` file in the current directory. It will install all packages listed under the "dependencies" key.

## How can I run npm successfully?

You already are running npm successfully and require no changes to your path. Try these commands to get a feel for how to use npm properly.

```bash
npm init # just follow the prompts and accept the default answers
npm install --save express # add a dependency
cat package.json # view the resulting package.json file
```

Comment: Thanks code_monk, your help is very much appreciated!

I signed up to a Code Academy React course about five years ago so when I run 
"cat package.json" I get a few git repository urls that are now defunct;

eg:
"homepage": "https://github.com/iancraig/jammming#readme"

Can I delete these manually by editing the package.json file?

Comment: Yes. You can use the [npm uninstall](https://docs.npmjs.com/uninstalling-packages-and-dependencies) command to remove the entry from package.json, and the corresponding directory in `./node_modules`.

Comment: Hi Code Monk - may I ask you a further question? I am learning React from a Udemy course. I'd like to install and run React from a downloaded course folder:
/Users/iancraig/TRAINING/REACT/01-starting-setup.
Do I have to run npm install each time I want to create a new React project in a specific folder? Having run npm install, when I enter npm start in terminal I get: npm ERR! Missing script: "start".....what's happening here? I'm finding setting up the very basics to be quite difficult..thanks for any light/advice you can shed on this.

Comment: First you must cd into the directory: `Users/iancraig/TRAINING/REACT/01-starting-setup`. Then run `npm install`. Then probably something like `npm start`. If you have the error "missing script 'start'", then you should examine the package.json file to see what scripts are available

Comment: Thanks for yr reply..I've cd'd into this directory:Users/iancraig/TRAINING/REACT/01-starting-setup. I've run npm install ok. When I run npm start I get:

Cannot find module '/Users/iancraig/TRAINING/REACT/01-starting-setup/app.js'

In the folder tree 'app.js' is in its own folder called 'src' and in this course project it's called App.js. It seems npm isn't able to look into nested folders..

Comment: In that case you should modify the line in package.json that corresponds to the key `{ "scripts: { "run": "some command app.js"}`. Modify it to say `some command src/app.js`